# Different behavior with delayed variable expansion in batch script in 2 identical piece of code

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

```
@echo off
pushd

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

set VARY=before
if "!VARY!" == "before" (
set VARY=2    
if "!VARY!" == "2" @echo If you see this, yes echo !VARY!
)


set VAR=before
if "!VAR!" == "before" (
set VAR=1
if "!VAR!" == "1" @echo If you see this, it worked
)

popd
```

Expected Output:
    If you see this, yes 2
    If you see this, it worked

Actual Output:
    If you see this, it worked

Can someone explain why is the output not showing "If you see this, yes 2" as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have trailing spaces after the `2`, so compare `if "2    " == "2"` (not equal).

To avoid this use the following code:

```
set "VARY=before"
if "!VARY!" == "before" (
set  "VARY=2"
if "!VARY!"=="2" echo If you see this, yes echo !VARY!
)
```

.. and if you set numbers, you can also use "set /a":

```
set "VARY=before"
if "!VARY!" == "before" (
set /a VARY=2
if "!VARY!"=="2" echo If you see this, yes echo !VARY!
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Silly of me to not notice the blank spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. The first time you set `VARY` to `2<space><space><space><space>` instead of `2`.

To avoid this use ALWAYS the syntax `set "VARY=2"`

This syntax only takes the input from the first to the last quote, all characters after the last quote are dropped.